# MFC Dialog Property Sheet usage produces errors in VS 2017, works on VS 2013

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog, visual-studio-2017

Have an existing `Visual Studio 2017` MFC dialog app project where the controls are getting too dense and complicated to add more functionality.

I wanted to employ a tabbed dialog interface to group and simplify the control layout. Found some useful articles detailing the usage of Property Pages and Sheets written for Visual Studio 2015.

Created the needed property page resource(s) for two tabs to start and created the style sheet in my Aps' `.cpp` file. Compiles fine but produces a runtime exception when it tries to create the dialog box:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7786C54F in Utlities.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: CResourceException at memory location 0x0040F430.

Stack window not very helpful for me.

Code segment:

```
CPropertySheet cSheet;
CConverter convTab; // class for first tab
CYield yieldTab;    // class for second tab
cSheet.AddPage(&convTab);
cSheet.AddPage(&yieldTab);
m_pMainWnd = &cSheet;
INT_PTR nResponse = cSheet.DoModal(); // Exception thrown here
```

I noticed that the `CPropertyPage` class was apparently replaced by `CMFCPropertyPage` as `CPropertyPage` is no longer listed as a parent class in VS 2017.

I thought that it may be incompatible with `CPropertySheet`. I found that using CMFCPropertySheet complies fine but produces the same error. So I went through and manually derived my Property pages from CPropertyPage and also derived the sheet from CPropertySheet. Same error.

On a whim I fired up an older computer that still had Visual Studio 2013 loaded and tried that by deriving from `CPropertySheet` and `CPropertyPages`. It worked just fine.

At a loss as to why VS 2013 works but VS 2017 won't. Would hate to downgrade my 2017 installation to 2015 just for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you rub it in debug mode? Still crashes? And, what happens if you remove one of the tabs? See if you can isolate which tab is the offending one.

Comment: According to here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cresourceexception-class it is implying a resource can't be found. Have you done a clean and full rebuild? Could one of your pages be using a resource that now has a different path in the newer IDE that before?

Comment: It crashes with or without debugger before displaying any window. Full rebuild does not help. PropertyPage(s) created using Add->New->Resource->Dialog / IDD_PropPage_Large. Class(s) for the pages were created with ClassWizard from the resource view. The full app was created on VS 2017, not imported from a previous version.

I installed VS 2015 on my older machine, and re-created the bare bones & resources from scratch. The code runs fine on 2015,

Opened the framework I made in VS 2015 in VS 2017, it runs without error. Re-created the framework in VS 2017 from scratch, same error.

Comment: I think you should raise this with Microsoft through the IDE support feature.

Comment: You have not shown how you are adding the dialog template to `CPropertyPage` drived classes. You are just confirming that you do have dialog templates. There should be something like `page1.Construct(IDD_PAGE1);` *"Call Stack window"* should also show detailed information.

Comment: I indicated I was deriving from CMFCPropertyPage under VS 2107 and CPropertyPage was no longer listed. I indicated that I tried deriving my sheet from CMFCPropertSheet. without sucess. I said I recreated the framework on VS 2015 using CPropertyPage and CPropertySheet and it works on both VS 2015 and VS 2017.

When I try to then add a CMFCPropertyPage resource to the working project I get the same error. Upon looking at the.h and .cpp files I see there are significant code differences in the construction of the object and DDX is completely missing from the CMFCPropertyPage object.
.

Comment: My conclusion is CMFCPropertyPage is incapatable with either CMFCPropertySheet or CPropertySheet in VS2017.

Comment: The class for the dialog templates was created using Class Wizard and derived from base class options provided. CPropertyPages in VS 2013 & 2015, CMFCPropertyPage in VS 2017. I created class variable and used .AddPage() in the code above to link them to the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue but managed to solve it. I'm in VS 2017.

My main code:

```
CMFCPropertySheet sheet;
CWizardPage1 page1; // class derived from MFCPropertyPage
CWizardPage2 page2; // class derived from MFCPropertyPage

sheet.AddPage(&page1);
sheet.AddPage(&page2);

sheet.DoModal();
```

This throws the same CResourceException at `sheet.DoModal()`.

What I changed to make it work is in the `CWizardPage1` constructor (and similar for `CWizardPage2`).

Constructor which results in an exception:

```
CWizardPage1::CWizardPage1()
{
}
```

Constructor which doesn't result in an exception:

```
CWizardPage1::CWizardPage1()
    : CMFCPropertyPage(IDD_WIZARD_PAGE1)
{
}
```